# Extracting terms from formula object in R

Tags: r, lm

Suppose I have a formula object in R, which would be something like

```
form <- formula(y ~ x1 + x2)
```

Where y, x1, x2 are vectors including, lets say, n numbers each.

Is there a way I can extract the values contained in y, from form?

Comment: The question is unclear. Object formula don't contain values.

Comment: @agstudy yes it does, see my answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try something like:

```
eval(form[[2]])
```

Normally you will have `y`, `x1` and `x2` as columns of a `data.frame`, e.g. `df`, and not objects in your global environment. In this case you can use:

```
eval(form[[2]], envir = df)
```

Comment: Why do you `eval` it?

Comment: @nico because the values are needed, `form[[2]]` is equal to `y`. In your answer `form` is the result of `lm(y ~ x1 + x2)` which is not what was asked.

Comment: @alko989 ops... I was fooled by the `lm` tag... and did not notice that the code said "formula"... my bad

Answer (score 0):

You will find the vectors in the `model` parameter of form

```
form$model
```

On a side note if you don't want to store the data in the form object just pass `model=F` to the `lm` call.

Comment: This only works if form is a lm object, but I might end up using this approach, so I appreciate your answer